# Using OWL API to query BBC Wildlife Ontology

Tags: rdf, owl, owl-api

Is it possible to use the OWL API to query this ontology, http://www.bbc.co.uk/ontologies/wildlife/2010-11-04.shtml, I'm getting a huge confusion about it. Its mention its in RDF, my confusion is, it it an OWL Ontology serialize in RDF syntax? If so, then I suppose it should load with the OWL API?

Comment: The link you provided refers to an HTML page. The page reads "This ontology uses W3C's RDF technology", not "this *is* RDF", but I can't find a link to an RDF version of the ontology. Content negotiation doesn't give me RDF, so you should ask the BBC where the RDF is.

Comment: if you do a wget on the link of the ontology, http://purl.org/ontology/wo/, you an index.html which is in rdf, its in fact an rdf in itself

Comment: @BenCompanjen According to the BBC's [Nature Feeds and Data](http://www.bbc.co.uk/nature/feedsanddata) page, they use content type negotiation, so if you request http://www.bbc.co.uk/ontologies/wildlife/2010-11-04.rdf you can get the ontology. As [loopasam's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15989669/1281433) points out, loading from Protégé will also get the RDF version.  This is really what content type negotiation is for, but it's so rarely implemented that we rarely expect it, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file containing the ontology (purl.org/ontology/wo) doesn't seems to be available as mentioned in the comments. (EDIT: It's possible to load the file via Protege: "Open as URI" --> `http://purl.org/ontology/wo/`) However, the terms are listed further down the HTML page, so you could recreate it yourself if needed.

The ontology should be representable using RDFS axioms (ranges, domains, subproperties and subClasses) or using OWL. You can serialise the ontology in RDF/XML or any OWL syntax, both format are handled by the OWL-API.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm loading the ontology in Protege and getting many issues, i created a question for this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15988321/owl-property-loading-as-annotation, if you can help, that would be great

Comment: OK, how are you loading the ontology inside Protege? Are you entering the values manually by hand or are you loading from an URL (if yes could you post it please)? I will then try to answer on the other thread.

Comment: Actually I found it and added it to the answer.