# OWL ObjectProperty loading as annotation in Protégé

Tags: rdf, ontology, owl, protege

I'm trying to load an [ontology](http://www.bbc.co.uk/ontologies/wildlife/2010-11-04.shtml) in Protégé but it is not processed as expected. Most problematic is that all the Object and Data Properties appear as Annotation instead of Data Property and Object Property.

I have an Object Property *kingdom*:

```xml
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&wo;kingdom">
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">kingdom</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:comment xml:lang="en">associates a taxon rank with a kingdom</rdfs:comment>
    <vs:term_status>testing</vs:term_status>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&wo;Kingdom"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&wo;TaxonRank"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>
```

`/nature/life/Chordate#kingdom` has the value `/nature/life/Animal#kingdom` for as its kingdom:

```xml
<wo:Phylum rdf:about="/nature/life/Chordate#kingdom">
    <rdfs:label>Vertebrates</rdfs:label>
    <wo:kingdom rdf:resource="/nature/life/Animal#kingdom"/>
</wo:Phylum>
```

However, in Protégé, the property is showing as an annotation. I do not understand why it is not showing as an object property to kingdom.

[image]

Why is this?

Comment: I can find the first snippet of code in the ontology (serialised as RDF/XML) but not the second one. Could you tell me which line number it is? The first object property you mention (`kingdom`) appears correctly with Protege 4.2

Comment: This is a link of the rdf file I'm using, https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108022472/index.rdf, In the attached file, I've only loaded enough to see the problem. I have loaded the whole needed data to represent this individual http://www.bbc.co.uk/nature/life/Nephrurus, i.e. the kingdom,animal,reptile. If you see the individual with name "Geckos" with Type "Family" and having IRI http://www.bbc.co.uk/nature/life/Gecko#family, it has all the Data and Object properties as annotation which is actually the problem I'm getting.

Comment: I found the following individual: `<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Gecko"><owl:sameAs rdf:resource="http://www.bbc.co.uk/nature/life/Gecko#family"/></owl:NamedIndividual>` in the file, there is however no annotations attached to it. I still can't find the second code snippet either.

Comment: Ok, when I'm viewing the individual gecko in Protege, I'm seeing it like this, https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108022472/gecko.png

Comment: @loopasam, as you are saying, I'm not seeing any annotation in the file, there are object properties still being seen as annotation

Comment: I've downloaded protege 4.2 and tried it, yet same issue :(

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug in Protege. How to fix it:

- Open your file `index.rdf` with Protege, it takes a bit of time in order to import some files.
- Save the ontology in RDF/XML format, pick the folder when you want to put it and call it `ontology.owl`. The extension is important, save it as OWL file.
- Close Protege and re-open it, open the file `ontology.owl`, you should now see the property correctly displayed.

Why is it doing that? I believe Protege gets confused by the .rdf and interprets wrongly the data.

Comment: for the "animalia" individual of type TaxonName, all except wo:kingdomName are showing up as annotation

Comment: The ontology uses ambiguously the same properties like `scientificName`, they are declared in the same time to be annotation properties and data properties. Because of that Protege get's confused on which one to show. You have to transform/remove the annotation properties in order to discard the ambiguity, it should be possible to do by removing the blocks like  `<owl:AnnotationProperty rdf:about="http://purl.org/ontology/wo/scientificName">...</owl:AnnotationProperty>` from the OWL file.

Comment: Does it actually work for you when you delete the AnnotationProperty? because for me, when I delete neither the annotation now appears because of course i've deleted it and not even the data properties

Comment: I have tried with `scientificName` and it worked, you have to delete only the annotation properties and make sure you delete all the XML block attached to them.

Comment: Unfortunately, I deleted all, in fact, i created a little python script that does it but still doesn't solve the problem of the data property. That's my [ontology.owl](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108022472/v1/ontology.owl). Also, this [textfile](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108022472/v1/files.txt) include all the imports I'm using including the python script that removes the annotation properties

Comment: to run the python script for removing the annotation, simply do python  removeUnusedTags.py <filename>

Comment: This ontology is really messed-up, I advise that you look at a different one if possible. Annotations have been well removed, but I guess you are now looking at the wrong individual that's why you think that data properties are disappearing. There are indeed 2 individuals with rdfs:label `animalia` (look around line 2700 of the file). If you remove the first one, then you can then see the good one in Protege, with data properties there as expected.

Comment: I wanted to select a different one but this one contains lot of background knowledge, if you know anyone as good or better than this one, please let me know

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve so it's difficult to provide pointers. Good luck anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you find that your object properties appear as annotations, the solution is to export as ontology.
That will turn your annotations into classes.

Answer (score 0):

When I save my ontology as RDF/XML format, object property of instance becomes annotations. However, if the ontology is saved as Turtle Syntax, object property will be shown normally when opened with protege again.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem: "Object Properties" were shown as "Annotation Properties". The reason was that the triples defining these properties as "Object Properties" were not present in my ontology, since the import did not work correctly:
The import statement was  (using ttl syntax):

```
<http://my.great.ontology/resources20230621/> owl:imports ifc: .
```

The prefix was defined

```
@prefix ifc: <http://standards.buildingsmart.org/IFC/DEV/IFC4/ADD2_TC1/OWL#> .
```

Nevertheless Protege decided to give the imported statement the Ontology IRI https://standards.buildingsmart.org/IFC/DEV/IFC4/ADD2_TC1/OWL# (while still using the "Location" http://standards.buildingsmart.org/IFC/DEV/IFC4/ADD2_TC1/OWL#)

[image]

So, I ended up, with all statements in the imported ontology having URIs starting with "https://" while the ones from my file were resolved to "http://....". I fixed it by changing the prefix definition to

```
@prefix ifc: <https://standards.buildingsmart.org/IFC/DEV/IFC4/ADD2_TC1/OWL#> .
```